# If $\alpha(s)$ is an oval, prove that $\mathbf{t}$'' is parallel to $\mathbf{t}$ at at least four points.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

If $\alpha(s)$ is an oval, prove that $\mathbf{t}$'' is parallel to $\mathbf{t}$ at at least four points.

Attempt:

Using the Four Vertex Theorem we know the oval has at least four vertexes, so at these four points curvature has a relative maximum or minimum. Let k be the curvature.

Since  k(s) = $<\mathbf{t}′(s),\mathbf{n}(s)>$ then k'(s) = $<\mathbf{t}′′(s),\mathbf{n}(s)> + <\mathbf{t}′(s),\mathbf{n}′(s)>$.

Since k'(s) = 0 at the four vertex $<\mathbf{t}''(s), \mathbf{n}(s)> + <\mathbf{t}'(s), \mathbf{n}'(s)>$ = 0 at these four points.

Now since $\mathbf{t}'(s)$ = k(s)$\mathbf{n}(s) \rightarrow$ k'(s) = $<\mathbf{t}''(s), \mathbf{n}(s)> + <k(s)\mathbf{n}(s), \mathbf{n}'(s)>$

I can write that $<k(s)\mathbf{n}(s), \mathbf{n}'(s)>$ = 0 at the four vertex because k(s) is just a constant and $\mathbf{n}(s)$ and $\mathbf{n}'(s)$ are perpendicular?

Then $<\mathbf{t}''(s), \mathbf{n}(s)>$ = 0, and from this I know that $\mathbf{t}''(s)$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{n}(s)$.

Also I know that $\mathbf{n}(s)$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{t}(s) \rightarrow \mathbf{t}(s)$ is parallel to $\mathbf{t}''(s)$ at these four points.

Does this proof work?

Comment: Oops. So if $k'=|\mathbf t''|$, then it would follow that since $|\mathbf t|=1$, then $|\mathbf t'|=0$? You need to differentiate $|\mathbf f|$ more carefully. (Hint: Write this in terms of dot product.)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin k(s) = $<\mathbf{t}'(s), \mathbf{n}(s)>$ then k'(s) = $<\mathbf{t}''(s), \mathbf{n}(s)> + <\mathbf{t}'(s), \mathbf{n}'(s)>$. Thank you for your help I'm still new to this, is this heading in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. Or use $k(s)^2 = \langle \mathbf t'(s),\mathbf t'(s)\rangle = 2\langle \mathbf t''(s),\mathbf t'(s)\rangle$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you so much for your help in this problem! I edited my post correcting my previous mistakes, and I think I was able to finish the proof. If you get a chance could you let me know if this looks correct. Thanks.

Comment: Well done. I've made a few minor suggestions in the answer, so you can accept it and your question will no longer appear unanswered :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You're most welcome. Enjoy learning some differential geometry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have it, basically.  More seriously,  $\langle\mathbf t'(s),\mathbf n'(s)\rangle = 0$ for all $s$, not just at the vertices, as $\mathbf t'(s)$ is a multiple of $\mathbf n(s)$ and $\mathbf n'(s)$ is a multiple of $\mathbf t(s)$. Perhaps you should emphasize at the end that since you're working in $\Bbb R^2$, any vector orthogonal to $\mathbf n(s)$ must be a scalar multiple of (parallel to) $\mathbf t(s)$.